# Efficiently: Random numbers in fixed range without repetitions

Tags: oop, random, performance

Hey guys, I know that there are a million questions on random numbers, but exactly because of that I searched a lot but I couldn't find something similar to mine - without implying it's not there. In any case, pardon me if I am repeating a question, just point me to it if that's the case.

So, I wanna do something simple in the most efficient way.

I want to generate randomly all `N` integers in the range `[0, N]`, one by one, such that there are no repetitions.

I know, I can do this by inserting everything in a `list`, shuffle it, get the head and then remove head from the list. But then I will have shuffled my list of length `N`, `N-1` times.

Any better / faster idea?

Comment: Technically (or I guess ideally) it's just as random to shuffle once as it is to shuffle `N-1` times, isn't it?

Comment: What language? Some languages have lib functions for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do one shuffle, and then step through the list.

I'd recommend a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked a few times, and in each case the correct answer given is to shuffle an array (either the original, or an array of indices), however this isn't a satisfactory answer in cases where the number of possible indices is prohibitively large (either it's huge, or memory is tight, or you simply crave maximum efficiency for whatever reason).

As such I want to add an alternative for the sake of completeness. Now, this isn't truly random, so if that's what you need then **do not use this**, however, if your goal is simply "good enough" with minimal memory requirements then the following pseudo-code may be of interest:

```
function init:
    start = random [0, length)      // Pick a fully random starting index
    stride = random [1, length - 1) // Pick a random step size
    next_index = start

function advance_next_index:
    next_index = (next_index + stride) % length
    if next_index is equal to start then
        start = (start + 1) % length
        next_index = start
```

Here's an example of how to implement a re-usable function for grabbing pseudo-random values:

```
counter = length
function pseudo_random:
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter is equal to length then
        init()
        counter = 0
    advance_next_index()
    return next_index
```

Quite simply `pseudo_random` will call `init` once every `length` iterations, thus re-shuffling the "random" pattern of results produced by `advance_next_index`, and ensure that for every `length` values there is not a single duplicate.

To reiterate; this isn't a particularly random algorithm, so it **must not** be used in situations where true randomness is required. However, the results are random enough for some basic, non-critical, tasks, and it has a tiny memory footprint. For example, if you just want to randomise some behaviour in a game to avoid something becoming repetitive, or the data-set is large and never exposed to the user (in which case it is effectively random to them) it would take a long time to piece together the order and somehow exploit it.

If anyone knows of any better algorithms with similar properties then please share!